# one-to-many relation and multiple conditions using Criteria

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, criteria, hibernate-criteria, restrictions

I have 2 tables:

1. a master `table` with single attributes of some objects `(id, name, title, ...)`
2. a table with repeating attributes `(master_id, attribute_name, attribute_value)`

Example data for #2:

```
 - 10, "authors", "John Bill"
 - 10, "authors", "Merry J"
 - 10, "owners", "Chris O."
 - 11, "authors", "Andrew K."
```

It's a one-to-many relation:

```
<set name="repeating" table="xxx" cascade="none" mutable="false" lazy="true"    fetch="join">
<key column="...."/>
<one-to-many class="...." />
</set>
```

I want to find the master object `(id=10)` where `"authors" = "John Bill"` and `"authors" = "Merry J"` and `"owners" = "Chris O."`

For the first condition I can do it in that way:

```
session.createCriteria(Master.class)
.createCriteria("repeating")
.add(Restrictions.eq("attributeName", "authors"))
.add(Restrictions.eq("attributeValue", "John Bill"))
.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```

How can I add other conditions using Criteria?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is detached criteria

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forEntityName("repeating")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("attributeName", "authors"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("attributeValue", "John Bill"))
    // other rows
    .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Property.forName("masterId")));

session.createCriteria(Master.class)
    .add(Property.forName("id").in(dc))
    .list();
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not OK. "owners" is a value for "attributeName". It means that it should be done in that way:
`.add(Restrictions.eq("attributeName", "owners"))
.add(Restrictions.eq("attributeValue", "Chris O.")) ` 

But in that case it will not return any results.

Comment: sorry for my mistake. then I suggest you use `Restrictions.disjunction()` to build you criteria, or in this case, you may find HQL easier to write.